# How do I use composite strategies in hypothesis (hypothesis.errors.InvalidArgument: Expected SearchStrategy but got function)

Tags: python-hypothesis

This example is a variation of the one in the [docs](http://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data.html#composite-strategies):

```py
import hypothesis.strategies as st
    
from hypothesis import given
    
@st.composite
def s(draw):
    x = draw(st.text(), min_size=1)
    y = draw(st.text(alphabet=x))
    return (x, y)
    
    
    
@given(s1=s, s2=s)
def test_subtraction(s1, s2):
    
    print(s1, s2)
    
    assert 0
```

It fails:

```
E hypothesis.errors.InvalidArgument: Expected SearchStrategy but got <function accept.<locals>.s at 0x7fd7e5c05620> (type=function)

/mnt/work/unfuncat/software/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/hypothesis/internal/validation.py:40: InvalidArgument
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what's `draw` here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to call the composite functions. This is not explained in the docs, but there is an example in a [2016 blog post](https://hypothesis.works/articles/generating-the-right-data/).

```py
@given(s1=s(), s2=s()) # <===== change
def test_subtraction(s1, s2):
    
    print(s1, s2)
    
    assert 0
```

Comment: There's also [an example in the docs](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data.html#composite-strategies) (`list_and_index`), but I agree this should be explicitly stated in the text.

Comment: It is shown how to produce one example in the REPL. It is not clear to me that means that you have to use function calls in the given statements. Regular strategies are used without function calls. I think it would be helpful to write that composites are different :)